# Apache flink with AWS kinesis consume data-Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kinesis/FlinkKinesisConsumer

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis-analytics

Here is my code for connecting aws kinesis. When I'm trying to connect with FlinkKinesisConsumer it's throwing an error like Classnotfound exception.

```
import configs.AWSConfigConstants;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesisanalytics.runtime.KinesisAnalyticsRuntime;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.config.ConsumerConfigConstants;

public class StreamingJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final StreamExecutionEnvironment sEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
            String region = "us-east-1";
            String inputStreamName = "";
            String accesskey = "";
            String secretkey = "";
            String initPosition = "LATEST";
            String arn = "";
            
            Properties consumerConfig = new Properties();           
            consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, region);
            consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, accesskey);
            consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, secretkey);
            consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ROLE_ARN, arn );          
            consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, initPosition);

            System.out.println("Consume config properties:");
            System.out.println(consumerConfig);
            
            DataStream<String> kinesisInputStream = sEnv.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>
            (inputStreamName,new SimpleStringSchema(),consumerConfig));
            
            System.out.println(kinesisInputStream);
            sEnv.execute("Flink Streaming Processor");          
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this below error

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1feK.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the appropriate version of the connector in your build. Something like this, where 2.11 is the scala version, and 1.13.2 is the Flink version.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

For more info, see [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/kinesis/).

Comment: I've added those in my dependencies. Even though it's not working. 

Now I'm facing this issue. If any of you aware of this please help me.

org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource@12591ac8
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No operators defined in streaming topology. Cannot execute.

Anyway thanks for your reply David.

Comment: Every flink job must have at least one source and one sink. You need to add a sink.

Comment: After adding the sink I was trying to print the result of addsource storing variable. The below one was the result I'm getting.

org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource@17503f6b
Job has been submitted with JobID 536da6a4fb932045cb7dba17657f45d0
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 536da6a4fb932045cb7dba17657f45d0)

I don't know what is the output is saying here. Please help me David.

Comment: I suggest you work your way through the tutorials and examples in the documentation, starting here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/learn-flink/overview/

Comment: I'm getting this below exception now inside my flink job under failed section. Can you please help me here how to clear this exception?

Caused by: org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.AmazonKinesisException: User: ****************** is not authorized to perform: kinesis:ListShards on resource: ********************************* (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: ****************************************; Proxy: null)